# Cosine of a measurable set has smaller measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a measurable subset of $[0,1]$ such that $|A| >0$, i.e., $A$ has positive measure. Prove that the set $\cos(A) = \{\cos x: x \in A\}$ has strictly smaller measure than $A$.

The cosine graph tells us that the function is one-one at $[0,1]$ and clearly the measure of $[\cos 1,1]$ is smaller than $1$. But other than that I have no idea how to even begin. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_{\cos(1)}^{\cos(0)}f(t)\,\text{d}t=\int_0^1f(\cos(x))\sin(x)\,\text{d}x$

where you can regard $f(t)$ as the indicator function of $\cos(A)$.

In this way, since $\cos(x)$ is a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[\cos(1),\cos(0)]$,

we have that $f(\cos(x))$ is the indicator function of $A$.

$\\$

Now, how large is $\sin(x)$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$?

Comment: Well, the second integral is simply $|A|$, whereas for the first one, the value of $\sin x$ from $0$ to $1$ is, again, contained strictly within $[0,1]$. It sort of explains why the integral is smaller in value, but how do I write it out explicitly? I'm not very sure how do I compute the integral of the product of the indicator function with a function, or at least write it out nicely.

Comment: @KelvinLian $\displaystyle\int_{\cos(1)}^{\cos(0)}f(t)\,\text{d}t=\int_0^1f(\cos(x))\sin(x)\,\text{d}x$ works for all Lebesgue-integrable functions $f:[\cos(1),\cos(0)]\to\mathbb{R}$, including any indicator function of a measurable subset of $[\cos(1),\cos(0)]$.

Comment: @KelvinLian The change of variables theorem yields that for measurable $A \subset [0, 1]$, $$m(\cos(A)) = \int_{A}|\cos'(x)|\,dx.$$ Then a bound on the integrand gives the result.

Comment: @ChrisSanders I let $B$ denote the set $\cos A$, and $1_B$ be the indicator function. So the measure of $B$ is written as $\int ^{\cos 0}_{\cos 1}1_B(t)dt$. When you make the substitution $t = \cos x$, we get $\int ^1 _0 1_B(\cos x)\sin x dx$. I'm thinking of using $$\int^1 _0 1_B(\cos x) \sin x dx = \sin \alpha \int^1 _0 1_B(\cos x) dx.$$

Comment: By the injectivity of cosine on $[0,1]$, $1_B(\cos x)$ is actually the indicator function of $A$ (as you already mentioned), and so the above integral becomes $(\sin \alpha) |A|$, for some $\alpha \in [0,1]$. But the above equality works if both functions are continuous on $[0,1]$, which I don't think the indicator function will satisfy...

Comment: @KelvinLian yeah you can put it that way. Or just more directly, $g$ is a non-negative function, and $0\leq\sin(x)\leq\sin(1)<1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$; therefore $0\leq g(x)\sin(x)\leq \sin(1)g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$; then take the integrals.

Comment: @ChrisSanders of course your way should've been the obvious way to do it... don't know why I would go out to look for another result. Thanks a lot.